# If/Else /extracting part of a string

Tags: java, if-statement

I am doing a project at the moment and am kind of stumped with one aspect of it,

The project tag is:

> Create a class encapsulating the concept of a file. Include a constructor, getter/setter, toString method, equals method. The added bit is to one I have trouble with
>
> *Also write a method returning the extension of the File, i.e. the letters after the last dot(.) in the
> filename
> If the filename is hello1.doc, then the method should return doc
> If there is no dot(.) in the filename, then the method should return “unknown extension”*

Here is my code so far for the File class proper

```
public class File {

private String fileName;

public File()
{

}

public File(String fn)
{
    this.fileName = fn; 
}


public String getName()
{       
    return this.fileName;
}


public void setName(String name)
{
    this.fileName = name;
}


public String toString()
{
    return fileName;

}


public boolean equals(File f1)
{


    if (f1.getName().equals(fileName))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}


public  void String(File f1){
    if (f1.toString().contains(".")){
        String h=f1.toString();
        String[] parts = h.split(".");
        String i= parts[0];
        String j= parts[1];
        System.out.println("File is of type"+" "+parts[1]);

    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Unkown file extension.");}

}

}
```

I am completely stumped as to how to complete this. I **think** the problem is that when I instantiate a new 'file' object the string isn't passed through my final if/else. A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciate :)

Cheers

Ps here is my test class (I know the if/else should be in the main file above :) )

```
public class Filemain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {



        File f1 = new File();

        File f2 = new File ("test.pdf");
        File f3= new File ("results.doc");

        System.out.println(f2);
        System.out.println(f3);



        if (f2.equals(f3))
        {
            System.out.println("You have not got complete documentation");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have the complete documentation");



        }
```

Comment: Is there any issue with your code? What's the question really?

Comment: Here is a hint `lastIndexOf()` on the `String` object is what you are looking for.

Comment: The issue is that when I run the test class, the part about the extension doesn't appear. I think I may have gone about is arseways.

Comment: @DanWyer did my answer helped you or you need more help?

Comment: Hi Guys, Turns out the problem overall was that when I initialized a 'File' object I forgot to put a () after each method call, simple as, the whole code is working now!, cheers. Dan.

PS Sorry if it was garbled, that's the state of my brain on this project!

Answer (score 2):

i think the problem is in the constructor when you do

```
f1.toString()
```

when you need to be doing

```
f1.getName()
```

plus your class name already exist in java, try using `MyFile` instead

finally you want to use

```
public void toString(File f1)
```

or

```
public void extString(File f1)
```

instead of

```
public  void String(File f1)
```

is it even compiling?

Answer (score 0):

`public  void String(File f1){` is not a valid constructor, this is a simple method that returns nothing.

Also the `toString()` method isn't overloaded so it will use the default implementation which is to not the filename.

```
int lastDot = f1.fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
if (lastDot >= 1) { System.out.println( f1.subString(lastDot); }
```

Will tell you where the extension starts if there is one and will print out the extension.

Everything else code wise that you posted is way incorrect and just noise.

Comment: The entirety of the code is way incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract the extension:

```
public String getExtension() {
    if (!fileName.contains("."))
        return "unknown extension";
    return fileName.replaceAll(".*\\.([^.]*)", "$1");
}
```

Although this might seem to be a curiosity, this is honestly how I would code it.

Comment: i did not down vote just saying :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one issue reproted - bad method/ constructor names.

For extn:

String has lastIndexOf,  use that? 5 lines :

```
String getExtn()
    int i =  fileName.lastIndexOf(".");//can use last index of character too
    String extn = “unknown extension”;
    if(i > -1 ){
        extn = fileName.subString(i + 1) ;
     }
    return extn;
}
```

One edge case is dot is last char - you should get an empty stirng then, can do something else by checking if i < fileName len